# Struggling to access very old DLL

Tags: com

We have a very old DLL that is no longer supported by a vendor, that we need to try and get working via a new piece of software as part of transitioning away from it.   It was written in 2000 (!) and we have a fair bit of documentation for it, telling us that it is an ActiveX iSAEDataObject component and has a number of services within it.

I've googled just about everything I can think of on the topic, and have seen there is a lot of references to making sure it is set to build as x86 (I have); I'm just trying to run it in the simplest of VB console applications to try and interact with it.

It registered successfully using regsvr32, and I can import it as a reference into my solution.   From there, there are 5 classes, but two have methods showing underneath them in Object browser, and the other three don't - only New().

But... even if I select one that does have a method and try to run it, it gives me this error:

**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {FDF93D0E-1D17-11D4-8F41-00C04F566282} failed due to the following error: 800a801d Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A801D.'**

I'm desperate to get this going, and have googled and googled; but can't seem to find much else other than the 32 vs 64 bit info.  Any help would be gratefully accepted :)

Have been working on it all day today, and have got a little further.   In the Object Explorer within Excel, I can see the methods - so hopefully inching forward; I just need to understand why I can't see them from within the iDE.

I also got rid of an error by downloading and registering MSRDO20.dll; so now am only left with (no doubt the most important!):

Could not determine the dependencies of the COM reference "iSAEDataObject". Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))

Comment: 0x800A801D is obscure, any error code that starts with 800A is specific to the component and need to be documented by the vendor.  There is a *hint* that it is an error related to the installation.  In other words, you need to use the vendor-provided installer to ensure that files and registry keys end up in the right place.  Talk to somebody in the company that is knowledgeable about the way the old app got deployed on users' machines.  SysInternals' ProcMon might show missing stuff, best compared to a trace obtained from a known-good machine.

Comment: Thanks so much Hans.   I've spent most of the day on it, and we've made some progress; I managed to get rid of one error by downloading and registering MSRDO20.dll, so am only left with this one:

Could not determine the dependencies of the COM reference "iSAEDataObject". Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))

Interestingly, my colleague found that he can view the methods on Excel Object Explorer; so just need to try and understand why we can view them there, but not in Visual Studio!

Comment: Ok, have got a bit further; I found an old computer running Windows XP and installed the software, and I can interact with the DLL via a VB script successfully (whereas I can’t on the windows 10 or server 2008R2 boxes).   So somehow I need to try and figure out what’s different between these two installs - would I look at file versions etc?

Comment: You can try the dependency walker (depends.exe) to track all dependencies of the library. The tool also will show what dependencies is absent. Please note, that if some dependencies are loaded in dynamic way (with LoadLibrary+GetProcAddress or something like this), the dependency walker will not show such a dependency.

Another way to track dependencies - is to use ProcessMonitor on working machine to see what libraries are loaded in the process with and without COM library referenced. The comparison of two cases will give you a list of dependencies of the library itself.